# How to fix "Cannot resolve the table name: [PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriod]" error in AR Aged Sensitive Report

Tags: acumatica

I am testing an upgrade from Acumatica Version 6.10.0755 to 2018 R2 in a development instance on my local Windows 7 computer. I have completed the upgrade process, and now when attempting to load the *AR Aged Period Sensitive* report (AR630500), the web interface returns a PXException:

*Cannot resolve the table name: [PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriod]*

I have examined the report in the report designer, and the *Build Schema* window loads the *FinPeriod* table with no problems. I compared it to the same report in 6.10.0755 and it appears that the report is the same.

The only lead that I have seen is that in the website's code repository, the location of the DAC definition, *FinPeriod.cs*, has moved; in 6.10.0755 it is located in *\PX.Objects\GL\DAC*.  But in 2018 R2 the FinPeriod.cs file is located in a new subfolder, *\PX.Objects\GL\DAC\FinPeriods.*

I have found no reference to this change in the structure of the GL module anywhere in any of the release notes, and I am at a loss as to what possibly went wrong.

First few lines of the stack trace:

```
[PXException: Cannot resolve the table name: [PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriod]]
   PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ReportNameResolver.ResolveTable(ReportTable t) 
   PX.Data.Reports.SoapNavigator.a(Object A_0, String& A_1)
   PX.Data.Reports.SoapNavigator.GetFieldSchema(Object field) 
   PX.Web.UI.PXReportViewer.r() 
...
```

Comment: First do IISReset and test. Second remove table from schema, save, close report designer, re-open designer and add the table back in the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer; it turned out the report was a customized version of the stock report that had been created (but not documented) before I started working on the project.  The upgrade process kept the customized report as-is with the old table references.  To correct this, I simply used the *File>Build Schema* menu option in the Report Designer, removed the old *FinPeriod* table, and added the *MasterFinPeriod* table, then used the *Refactor* button, which automatically mapped the relevant fields from the new table.

Answer (score 1):

According to Acumatica release notes table FinPeriod was renamed in 2018 R2. Right now I can't provide you the name of a new table. You need to find what is replacement for it by going through different release notes.

Comment: Thank you! The new table is _MasterFinPeriod_